# Shifting NSView also shifts other views for no apparent reason

Tags: swift, nsview

Through my code I shift the main view (`self.view`) using an `animator()` with the following code:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (_) in
    NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.5
    self.view.animator().frame.origin.x = 380

}) {
    print("finished")
}
```

And it does successfully shift my view, nevertheless I encounter an issue when adding another view to my main window using the following code:

```
let newView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
newView.wantsLayer = true
newView.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor(red: 150/255, green: 15/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1)
NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentView?.addSubview(newView)
```

I don't understand why this `newView` which is not associated to the other view shifts accordingly to `self.view` even if the main window presents the newView.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `self` the `contentViewController` of `NSApplication.shared.mainWindow`?

Comment: it's the view controller

Comment: Is that a yes or a no? Is the shifted `self.view` the same view as `NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentView`?

Comment: Probably yes, how can I add a separate view to the content view without adding it as a subview of self.view?

Comment: Add the shifting view to the content view.